# Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined GetJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm Stucked in a situation where i need to fix my codes when getting Jsonresult for my  Google Maps v3 but when i am in the loop to load my map with worker from jquery, this error shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`  i don't know how to fix this and i dont see some fixtures with this problem . I hope Someone can help me with this

This is my Codes for my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var minZoomLevel = 4;
        var zooms = 7;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: minZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

        // Listen for the dragend event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });


        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });


    }
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    function codeAddress() {
        $.getJSON("/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList", function (address) {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            $.each(address,function (index,currVal) {
               currVal = $(this).val();
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal
                        })


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(currVal);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        return true;
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
        codeAddress();
    }
</script>
```

This is the code for LoadWorkerList

```
   public JsonResult LoadWorkerList()
        {
            var workerList = new List<Worker_Address>();

            // check if search string has value
            // retrieve list of workers filtered by search criteria
            var list = (from a in db.Worker_Address
                        where a.LogicalDelete == false
                        select a).ToList();



            List<WorkerAddressInfo> wlist = new List<WorkerAddressInfo>();
            foreach (var row in list)
            {
                WorkerAddressInfo ci = new WorkerAddressInfo
                {
                    ID = row.ID,
                    Worker_ID = row.WorkerID,
                    AddressLine1 = row.Address_Line1 + " " + row.Address_Line2+ " " +row.City + " "+ GetLookupDisplayValById(row.State_LookID),
                    LogicalDelete = row.LogicalDelete

                };
                wlist.Add(ci);
            }


            return Json(wlist.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.AddressLine1), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The Error is in this ff: codes

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined 
v.fn.extend.val                          jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
(anonymous function)              $.each(address,function (index,currVal) {
v.extend.each                           jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
(anonymous function)              currVal = $(this).val();
l                                 jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
c.fireWith                        jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
T                                 jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
r
```

Comment: which browser are you using to test? inspect element in chrome, and on the line that this error show up there should be an arrow on the left, click that arrow to expand the stacktrace

Comment: paste the stacktrace here as part of the question, that is IF you cannot read a stacktrace, otherwise that should tell you exactly where in your code you're going wrong

Comment: @pythonian29033 Added stacktrace.

Comment: put this code: `alert(address);` directly after the line: `$.getJSON("/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList", function (address) {` and paste the results in the question please...

Comment: @pythonian29033 it says [object Object], [object Object] :) Thanks

Comment: ok looks like two elements, now under the line `$.each(address,function (index,currVal) {` put `alert("element no. " + index + ": " + address[index]);` count how many times this pops up and tell me which one of them says undefined

Comment: @pythonian29033 it appears 1 time and it says `element no. 0 [object Object]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40169/discussion-between-pythonian29033-and-enrique-gil)

Answer (score 0):

ok, judging by the stacktrace, it's saying that; 
 - either the value being returned by `$(this).val()` in `currVal = $(this).val();` is undefined at a certain index, or
 - the value of one of the indexes in `address` at `$.each(address,function (index,currVal)` is undefined.

make sure that the index value in `$.each(address,function (index,currVal) {` is not going beyond the length of `address` and that ALL the elements in `address` is assigned a value

I'm guessing you're trying to do geocoding on an address in the array `address`, and it's trying to make the address a lowerCase string, but there's no string being found.

if `address` is not an array, make it an array, it shouldn't be a string

Comment: Thanks but can you help me with that?